# How do you add headers to a Net::Http::Post request in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, http-headers, net-http

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  How do I add headers to a Net::HTTP::Post request?  I tried

```
    params = {"SubmitButton" => "View"}
    …
      headers = {"Referer" => url}
      req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri, params.to_query, headers)
```

However when I run this code I get the error

```
Error during processing: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/request.rb:14:in `initialize'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/marathon_guide_race_finder_service.rb:97:in `new'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/marathon_guide_race_finder_service.rb:97:in `block in process_race_link'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:187:in `block in each'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in `upto'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:186:in `each'
```

Note I want to add the headers to the object before it is sent.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the instance to make the post with headers

```
headers  = {"Referer" => url}
http     = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host)
response = http.post(uri.path, params.to_query, headers)
```

Comment: Thanks but  I want to add the headers to the object before it is sent.  How can I add the headers into the POST request object itself or is that impossible?

Comment: The request will not be made until the `http.post` call which in the code above will have your headers correctly attached.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from T J's method (providing the headers as a parameter to the `post()` call), you can also set the headers on the `HTTPRequest` object itself using `:[]`:

```rb
uri = URI('http://example.com/cached_response')
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
req['If-Modified-Since'] = file.mtime.rfc2822
```

<sub>Source: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.8/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Setting+Headers</sub>

This allows you to set the headers outside of performing the request.

The same approach works for `Net::HTTP::Post` objects:

```rb
params = {"SubmitButton" => "View"}
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri, params)
req['Referer'] = url
```